# cross scripting permission denied in javascript

Tags: javascript, scripting, cross-domain, permission-denied

Have an app A hosted on port 80 with a hostname of mycompany.net

Have app B hosted on 8080 of the same server with hostname sub.mycompany.net.

Page 1 of app A opens Page 2 of app B.  On Button Click of Page 2 of App B, I want to be able to update some text on Page1 of app A.

Have tried setting the document.domain of page 2 of app B to mycompany.net.

No luck.  How do I overcome the 'Permission Denied' error.  Help please....

Comment: How are you opening the 2 different pages?  Are they in separate browser windows?

Comment: Why the down votes on this question, people? The OP is encountering a very common problem, and the question is well asked.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ensure that you set `document.domain` in Page 1, even if it's already set to `mycompany.net` (strange, I know). The reason why is that unless you write to `document.domain`, the port number is fixed to port 80 (even though it's not in the property value), denying Page 2 access. Writing to the property sets this hidden port restriction to null. See [Same origin policy for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for more details.